# Is there a way to start vim in read only mode

Tags: linux, vim, text-editors

I use /bin/view as it is a safe way to view text files and not have accidental changes persist once I am finished.

/bin/view seams to be lack features that normal vim has. Is there a way to start vim in read only mode, or start /bin/view with visual mode.

I want to be able to select text and paste it with out having to use my mouse. Visual mode make it so easy to do that.

The problem I am having is related to CentOS / redhat Linux distros, is the -visual in view.

```
# vim --version | grep visual
+user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo +vreplace 
# view --version | grep visual
-textobjects -title -toolbar -user_commands -vertsplit -virtualedit -visual
```

Comment: `view` is a link (usually symbolic these days) to `vim` that runs `vim` in read-only mode. Your `view` seems to be linked to a different `vim` than the one you get from executing "vim". Take a look at the update-alternatives(8) man page to see how to fix that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

See `$ vim --help` for Vim's many launch arguments.

For launching Vim in read only mode that would be:

```
$ vim -R filename
```

*EDIT*

`$ view` and `$ vim -R` seem to be one and the same by way of symbolic links. I'm not sure what features you'll gain from running `$ vim -R` that you don't have with `$ view`.

Here, on Ubuntu, I can visually select stuff in both.

Comment: In centos view and vim -R are not the same. view is compiled with -visual for some reason.

Answer (score 11):

If you forgot the `-R` option when start up `vim`, you can use:

```
:set ro
```

Comment: When you use :set ro, how do you enable writing egain?

Comment: @Makmeksum `:set noro` or `:set noreadonly`; or when quitting use `:wq!`

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is simply not to overwrite the original file, you can vim's read from stdin feature:

```
cat filename | vim -
```

Answer (score 1):

As @garyjohn mentioned, `view` is often symbolically linked to either `vi` or `vim`.  Depending on which Linux distribution you are using and how `vi` or `vim` were installed this could vary.  On my RHEL 6 system the output of `` ls -l `which view` `` shows that `/bin/view` is symbolically linked to `vi`.

So if you want the features of `vim` in read-only mode you would either need to alias `view` to `vim` or use `vim -R <filename>` solution provided by @kev (assuming you don't have privileges to change the symbolic links on the system in question).

Comment: This is what I did, and it works perfectly (where `vim` is any version/flavour of Vim). Now I can have a read-only window for viewing side-by-side diffs in `vim`, with another window also editing the actual file at the same time.